# Count the number of mouse clicks in one second

Tags: javascript, qt, qtscript

Hi I'm working on an application that I want to improve the performance.(I know the question is kinda lengthy one- I apologize.)

I will explain in detail its a bidding application that uses only  qtscript/qscript(kinda javascript) and no html.

When a user click on a Button, I want to point to a text field(For a normal user its okay like -1 or 2 clicks per second). But the user crazily click on button(5 -10 clicks per second - yeah some people click like that), it decreases the performance like the amount take delay to display because every click it points to focus on text field.

I'm thinking of some work around like if the user clicks more than 3 times in 1 second we call the focus function only after the last click- I don't know this is a right solution if you guys know anything better please suggest. Another problem is I can't use setInterval() and clearInterval().

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use an array to count the number of clicks where every index represents 100ms (use a timeout to change current index, mod array length), make it as long as you'd like (at least a second), perform an average over it.

Comment: Can you just temporarily disable the button after the first click?

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks..I will try that.
Sorry Jeffman, its a bidding application so a fraction of second is very important(clients will complain for losing their just a $1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)'s `_.throttle` function.

```
_.throttle = function(func, wait, options) {
  var context, args, result;
  var timeout = null;
  var previous = 0;
  options || (options = {});
  var later = function() {
    previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : new Date;
    timeout = null;
    result = func.apply(context, args);
  };
  return function() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
    var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    if (remaining <= 0) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
      previous = now;
      result = func.apply(context, args);
    } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
    }
    return result;
  };
};
```

It looks really complex, but a basic example would be:

```
var func = function(){alert("Only do this once every second");},
    throttled = _.throttle(func, 1000);

// Call func() three times in under a second, and
// you get 3 message boxes
func(); // alerts
func(); // alerts
func(); // alerts

// Call throttled() three times in under a second, and
// you only get a message box the first time
func(); // alerts
throttled(); // does nothing
throttled(); // does nothing

// ... wait >1 second ...
func(); // alerts
throttled(); // does nothing
throttled(); // does nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

**example.xhtml** - No frameworks, no script elements in the body and counts both left and right clicks.

Additionally you can add `e.preventDefault();` at the end of the anonymous `onclick` event function. Keep in mind that if you're trying to protect content you will ultimately fail against anyone smart enough to realize that if it's already on their computer (memory, cache, etc) that they already have it in their possession. If you're trying to protect images you *must* use watermarks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Click Counter</title>

<script type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var click_left = 0;
var click_right = 0;

window.onclick = function(e)
{
 if (e.which==1) {click_left++;}
 else if (e.which==3) {click_right++;}

 alert('Left clicks: '+click_left+'\n\nRight Clicks: '+click_right);
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div><p>Left or right click</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks John, I really appreciate your help, unfortunately I'm not using HTML in my application and it won't support native javascript function like alert, window.onclick events ect. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should add check that the text edit you want to select after user clicked certain button already has focus. That will dramatically reduce loading on event queue.

Second you can implement your own button (by subclassing) and play around with options, like for example just ignore clicks which came within certain (small) interval. In case user starts spawning clicks very fast, you can also 'visualise' it on a button in certain way, showing to a user that your application had limit reactions on user input, switching it off after specified timeout.